# Laravel QUERY does not result anything even if there is no condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My query was working fine till yesterday, but today, my query yields empty results. I tried even with no conditions like this

```
"select `person`.`name`, `path`, `person`.`username`, `price`, `service`, `person`.`city`, `person`.`streetaddress`, `person`.`postalcode`, `date` from `person` inner join `services` on `person`.`id` = `services`.`person_id` inner join `imagesforperson` on `person`.`id` = `imagesforperson`.`person_id` group by `person`.`name
```

This is my query when I try to debug it with toSql(). As you can see, I have not supplied any WHERE condition, but it still returns empty collection.

```
Collection {#212 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Can someone advice what could have gone wrong? Any tips to debug this issue?

I am using Larvel 5.4, using MySQL as database.

Code:

```
$person = \App\person::query()
        -> select (['person.name', 'path', 'person.username', 'price', 'service','person.city', 'person.streetaddress', 'person.postalcode', 'date'])
        -> groupBy('person.name')
        -> join ('services' , 'person.id', '=', 'services.person_id')
        -> join ('imagesforperson' , 'person.id', '=', 'imagesforperson.person_id')
        -> get();

dd($person) //to debug, this returns empty collection as posted above
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Try removing your array these inside your select `[` and `]`

Comment: Your query is against the sql standard because you select fields that are not in the group by list, nor are aggregated, nor are functionally dependent on the group by field. Unfortunstrly, mysql allows such queries under certain configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two inner joins on your query, which means that if those related records don't exist (like `services` and `imagesforperson`), you won't get any results. You might think about starting there. Maybe you could try removing the joins and/or making them left join or something so that your query would still return a `person` record even if no `services` or `imagesforperson` existed.

Comment: Left join actually worked. I think I am smart and educated, but things like this tell me that I am so stupid. Why am I so stupid, I should post that as the next question

Comment: Haha... Don't beat yourself up. I only suspected that was the issue because I've come up against the same thing several times myself :-)

Comment: Also, while you're at it, you might check out this awesome package for managing files that are associated with a model (i.e. images for person): https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary

Comment: Thank you so much, once again, bless you :)